# lxml xpath not finding anchor text

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

I have two xpaths and only one of them correctly pulls the job titles from the url below. Any idea why xpath1 (which I found using the 'inspect element/copy XPath' feature of Chrome) doesn't work, while xpath2 does?

```
import requests
from lxml import html

url = 'http://www.mynextmove.org/find/browse?c=54'

xpath1 = '//*[@id="content"]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[1]/a/text()'
xpath2 = '//a[contains(@href, "profile")]/text()'

page = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)

jobs = tree.xpath(xpath2)
print 'jobs:', jobs
```

xpath1 returns [], the empty list.

xpath2 returns ['Anthropologists', 'Archeologists', ...]

Comment: `/html/body/div/div[3]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/a` That is what FireBug shows for the first table

Try using the 'Copy XPath' option in FireBug to validate your XPath

Comment: Using Firebug **or** Chrome here is a bad idea -- that gives you the DOM as munged by the browser, not the original content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `tbody` it looks like change it to:

```
`xpath1 = '//*[@id="content"]/table[1]/tr/td[1]/a/text()'`
```

and try it.

This is what I get when I do that:

```
In [31]: tree.xpath(xpath1)
Out[31]:
['Anthropologists',
 'Archeologists',
 'Architects',
 'Architectural Drafters',
 'Biochemists & Biophysicists',
 'Civil Drafters',
 'Civil Engineers',
 'Environmental Engineering Technicians',
 'Environmental Engineers',
 'Geodetic Surveyors',
 'Lawyers',
 'Legal Secretaries',
 'Mapping Technicians',
 'Marine Architects',
 'Marine Engineers',
 'Paralegals & Legal Assistants',
 'Survey Researchers',
 'Surveying Technicians',
 'Surveyors',
 'Tax Preparers',
 'Transportation Engineers',
 'Veterinarians',
 'Veterinary Assistants & Laboratory Animal Caretakers',
 'Veterinary Technologists & Technicians',
 'Water/Wastewater Engineers']
```

Comment: that's odd. It has tbody in the browser, but not when requests.get pulls it. Thanks!

Comment: @offwhitelotus, not odd, completely normal. Browsers normalize the DOM; you should never use them if you want to know what the original tree looked like.

Comment: Thanks, @CharlesDuffy. So how do I know what the original tree looks like? Should I pull from requests.get, save to disk as html, open that file in a browser, then do 'inspect element?' Or would that result in the same behavior?

Comment: Yes, that would be the same behavior. Why use a browser at all, and not just read the HTML file as it exists on disk? You could also use a tool such as the BaseX GUI (assuming XHTML or otherwise an XML-compliant input file) if you want something a bit more graphical.

Comment: The browser is useful because there's a "copy xpath" button. I'll look into BaseX.

Comment: The "copy xpath" button is going to get you, as a rule, something that's very, very sensitive to details of HTML generation and page ordering. It may not be as fun, but writing your queries by hand is the Right Thing. (Example: `foo[@id='bar']` is **vastly** more likely to continue working through page layout changes than `foo[1]`).